# Why tuple needs type annotation in nom library?

Tags: parsing, rust, nom

I'm writing a parser using `nom` library in rust. When using [`tuple`](https://docs.rs/nom/latest/nom/sequence/fn.tuple.html) I encounter a problem. This snippet works fine:

```rust
use std::str;

use nom::bytes::complete::take_while1;
use nom::bytes::complete::{tag, take_while};
use nom::character::complete::{char, multispace0};
use nom::sequence::tuple;
use nom::IResult;


fn identifier(input: &str) -> IResult<&str, &str> {
  take_while1(is_ascii_alphanumeric)(input)
}

fn parameter_separator(input: &str) -> IResult<&str, &str> {
  let my_parser = tuple((multispace0, char(','), identifier));
  let (input, _) = multispace0(input)?;
  let (input, _) = char(',')(input)?;
  let (input, _) = multispace0(input)?;

  Ok((input, ""))
}
```

But when replacing the `identifier` parser with `multispace0` parser the compiler ask me to type annotate the `my_parser`.

```rust
fn parameter_separator(input: &str) -> IResult<&str, &str> {
  let parser = tuple((multispace0, char(','), multispace0));
  let (input, _) = multispace0(input)?;
  let (input, _) = char(',')(input)?;
  let (input, _) = multispace0(input)?;

  Ok((input, ""))
}
```

```rust
49  |   let parser = tuple((multispace0, char(','), multispace0));
    |       ------   ^^^^^ cannot infer type for type parameter `E` declared on the function `tuple`
    |       |
    |       consider giving `parser` a type
```

What is the difference? Why the second raises error?

Comment: your function has concrete types, but [`multispace0`](https://docs.rs/nom/latest/nom/character/complete/fn.multispace0.html) is generic, when you changed to use it the compiler was'nt able to infer the type for `multispace0`

Comment: @Bamontan what about the first `multispace0` used in the `tuple`?

Comment: yes that's the one i'm talking about, when do you use `my_parser` ?

Comment: @Bamontan I didn't, but using `let _ = tuple((multispace0, char(','), multispace0));` raises error as well.

Comment: yes, that's because there is no way for the compiler to infer the type on `multispace0`, so he is asking you to give it to it

Comment: `cannot infer type for type parameter E declared on the function tuple`, as `multispace0`is generic, if there is no way for the compiler to infer the type, that's what he is complaining about.

Comment: @Bamontan, Okay but why this works? ```  let my_parser = tuple((multispace0, char(','), identifier));
```

Comment: because `identifier` is not generic, it's already a concrete type, so there is no type inference needed.

Comment: @Bamontan but still I've used the `multispace0` once before, why the first time doesn't cause problem?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247428/discussion-between-bamontan-and-amir-reza-riahi).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tuple` has a generic parameter `E` which must be an instance of `ParserError<I>`.

In your second function, the compiler cannot infer the type of `tuple`'s `E` parameter from the context. In `tuple((multispace0, char(','), multispace0))(input)`, none of the arguments passed to `tuple` gives sufficient information of what `E` might be. Therefore, you are seeing the following error:

```
pub fn tuple<I, O, E: ParseError<I>, List: Tuple<I, O, E>>(
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ required by this bound in `tuple`
```

Your first example worked because `identifier` has the type `IResult<&str, &str>` which itself expands to `Result<(&str, &str), nom::Err<nom::error::Error<&str>>>`.

This allows the compiler to instantiate `E` to `nom::Err<nom::error::Error<&str>>` in the `tuple()` call.

Thus, if you define an alias for `multispace0` that does not leave `E` unspecified, the code would compile correctly:

```
fn narrowed_multispace0(input: &str) -> Result<(&str, &str), nom::Err<nom::error::Error<&str>>> {
  multispace0(input)
}

let _ = tuple((narrowed_multispace0, char(','), multispace0))(input);
```

Rust implements the Hindley-Milner type system which performs bidirectional type inference. This allows `E` to be inferred even from the function's result type as in the following example:

```
fn parameter_separator(input: &str) -> IResult<&str, &str> {
  map(  // To map (&str, &str, &str)` onto `&str`
    tuple((multispace0, char(','), multispace0)),
    |_| "test"
  )(input)
}
```